# How to initialize RSA::PrivateKey?

Tags: c++, rsa, public-key-encryption, crypto++

I'm trying to use Crypto++'s RSA encryption. The problem is how to initialize `RSA::PrivateKey` from number string?

The code to generate key pairs(from [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Rsa_cryptography))

```
cout << hex ;

AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
InvertibleRSAFunction params;
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 2048);

params.SetPublicExponent(65537);

const Integer& n = params.GetModulus();
const Integer& p = params.GetPrime1();
const Integer& q = params.GetPrime2();
const Integer& d = params.GetPrivateExponent();
const Integer& e = params.GetPublicExponent();

///////////////////////////////////////
// Dump
cout << "RSA Parameters:" << endl;
cout << " n: " << n << endl;
cout << " p: " << p << endl;
cout << " q: " << q << endl;
cout << " d: " << d << endl;
cout << " e: " << e << endl;
cout << endl;
```

So I get **n,d,e** string, should be able to initialize the private key, then I found some sample code [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA):

```
Integer n("0xbeaadb3d839f3b5f"), e("0x11"), d("0x21a5ae37b9959db9");

RSA::PrivateKey privKey;
privKey.Initialize(n, e, d);

RSA::PublicKey pubKey;
pubKey.Initialize(n, e);
```

The code works, it doesn't throw any exception. So I try to change the n,e,d to the string generated previously.

```
// n: b0f2bee69386528216049775704d402cb3ff443ca2ea25a74b11c1c9c321b7ea46327b4e413f532616812fece07d061cf96e373789b3b9b05d2d31174c700a066868d26c52b5d48e6dbaf664fac66ee31747133a6569e16d12f521b56a12aadd74e7cf2534353a5e338173b8f884a568a25173f3a33782f9047af59da9b21180534923e5210c3989851f0d69d68d92c272769fbf2a833e2f522f60f76bec12d3b194c2f3b945c913649e2be54295a2f58e7c040bf61421f01077fdf234ddfe73663deec8979256c721fd65c046a7d21530adec1af2922ed6a27004bf31a04cd57981ca22208572743b6b64d4d30b0efe446fc7608b4178ff8a0ba7db3e45ecf3h
// e: 10001h
// d: 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

RSA::PrivateKey privKey;
privKey.Initialize(n, e, d);
```

It crashes. I googled a while and found [some other tip](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes):

```
InvertibleRSAFunction params;
params.Initialize(n, e, d);

RSA::PrivateKey(params);
```

But it still crashes. What's the correct way of initializing a 2048-bit rsa private key?

Comment: So `RSA_PUB_KEY` is actually the modulus?

Comment: Have you changed the strings somehow? According to the documentation, the hex-encoded integers should end with `h`. See `std::ostream& operator<<` http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html#aa5f24aab6821fe59b7b161682b9a40cd

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct that the private_key and the public_key are two odd numbers, and they can replace each other. And I did modify the string that output from cout <<.  It does end with .h, I removed it and added "0x" before it,  it seems ok for CryptoPP::Integer.

Comment: Please try not to change the format. The ending "h" is important

Comment: Same problem if change "0x..." to "...h"

Comment: Post updated with some test.

Comment: You need to show us your code; and not code that works from the wiki. Its OK to cite the code from the wiki, but it just takes up space and we have to parse it when its not necessary for your problem. What is necessary is to see what you are actually doing, rather than descriptions of pseudo-code, like "I changed the wiki example to use my parameters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     // n: b0f2bee69386528216049775704d402cb3ff443ca2ea25a74b11c1c9c321b7ea46327b4e413f532616812fece07d061cf96e373789b3b9b05d2d31174c700a066868d26c52b5d48e6dbaf664fac66ee31747133a6569e16d12f521b56a12aadd74e7cf2534353a5e338173b8f884a568a25173f3a33782f9047af59da9b21180534923e5210c3989851f0d69d68d92c272769fbf2a833e2f522f60f76bec12d3b194c2f3b945c913649e2be54295a2f58e7c040bf61421f01077fdf234ddfe73663deec8979256c721fd65c046a7d21530adec1af2922ed6a27004bf31a04cd57981ca22208572743b6b64d4d30b0efe446fc7608b4178ff8a0ba7db3e45ecf3h
>     // e: 10001h
>     // d: 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
>     RSA::PrivateKey privKey;
>     privKey.Initialize(n, e, d);
> ```
>
> It crashes.

We need to see the actual code. I'm guessing two things. First (1), you are not using a try/catch, so the program terminates due to the uncaught exception. To fix this:

```
try
{
    // Some operation
}
catch (const Exception& ex)
{
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

Second (2), you are using strings rather than Integers in the call to `Iniaitialize`. To fix this:

```
string n = "b0f2bee693865282...8a0ba7db3e45ecf3h";
string e = "10001h";
string d = "246e365ca5e6f2de...9ec2172f7a5982edh";

Integer _n(n.c_str()), _e(e.c_str()), _d(d.c_str());
RSA::PrivateKey privKey;
privKey.Initialize(_n, _e, _d);
```

The second issue should have been caught by the compiler. You should consider using `-Wall` to get a basic set of compiler diagnostics.

---

There's a potential third issue. That's the "key fails to validate" case. If you add a try/catch as described in (1), then you may see an "Invalid key material" or similar from `CryptoMaterial` class. In this case, your parameters do not validate according to the checks performed by `Validate`.

`Validate` is called by `Initialize` using a low-level of thoroughness (the `level` parameter below). The `Validate` function can be found in the manual at [InvertibleRSAFunction::Validate](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_invertible_r_s_a_function.html#a35247205517f839220a16287917ce0ce). Following the link [Definition at line 247 of file rsa.cpp](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/rsa_8cpp_source.html#l00247):

```
  247 bool InvertibleRSAFunction::Validate(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, unsigned int level) const
  248 {
  249     bool pass = RSAFunction::Validate(rng, level);
  250     pass = pass && m_p > Integer::One() && m_p.IsOdd() && m_p < m_n;
  251     pass = pass && m_q > Integer::One() && m_q.IsOdd() && m_q < m_n;
  252     pass = pass && m_d > Integer::One() && m_d.IsOdd() && m_d < m_n;
  253     pass = pass && m_dp > Integer::One() && m_dp.IsOdd() && m_dp < m_p;
  254     pass = pass && m_dq > Integer::One() && m_dq.IsOdd() && m_dq < m_q;
  255     pass = pass && m_u.IsPositive() && m_u < m_p;
  256     if (level >= 1)
  257     {
  258         pass = pass && m_p * m_q == m_n;
  259         pass = pass && m_e*m_d % LCM(m_p-1, m_q-1) == 1;
  260         pass = pass && m_dp == m_d%(m_p-1) && m_dq == m_d%(m_q-1);
  261         pass = pass && m_u * m_q % m_p == 1;
  262     }
  263     if (level >= 2)
  264         pass = pass && VerifyPrime(rng, m_p, level-2) && VerifyPrime(rng, m_q, level-2);
  265     return pass;
  266 }
```

The remaining open question might be, where did `m_p`, `m_q`, etc come from? The answer is `Initialize` factors `n` based on `e` and `d`, and populates the [CRT values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) like `p`, `q`, `dp`, `dq`, etc. It speeds up computation later.

---

This may be related.... `e=10001h` tells me Crypto++ probably did not generate the key pair. If Crypto++ generated the key pair, then it would use [e=17](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_invertible_r_s_a_function.html#a1d400269a0d1305e93623299d8184e29) by default. How did you generate the key pair?

Comment: It does caused by the e=17. The exponent is fixed value 17 and cannot be modified when call `params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 2048);`.  My problem is that I modified the exponent after the key was already generated: `params.SetPublicExponent(65537);`, so it prints e==0x10001 but actually the key was generated with e==0x11.

Comment: thanks. It's caused by the exponent and seems solved. I'm using `openssl genrsa --out key.pem 2048` and `openssl rsa -in key.pem -text` to generate the key pair, for convenience.

Comment: ***`--out key.pem ...`*** - Crytpo++ has a PEM reader and writer on the Crypto++ wiki at [PEM Pack](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pem_pack). Its part of the [Category:Patch](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Category:Patch) initiative, where the library supplies stuff created by users that don't quite fit into the Crypto++ library proper. Its kind of like a central distribution point for user supplied content so you don't have to go hunting on the web for possible junk.